# Searching for a survey data to perform data analyses

Tags: survey

I have tried searching on the internet for some survey data (R datasets, datacentral etc) but only came across data set which had only a few observations or had only a few attributes.

I am looking to find a data set which would have a few rating questions and maybe a few open text questions such 'What's going well' and 'What needs improvement'.

Can anyone suggest or share any link where I can find that? I require such a data set only for visualization purposes

Comment: I just did a quick search, but the results of the xkcd survey are not yet published. That is sad.

Comment: hi, maybe asdfree.com  ?